# How to get the sub-string starting from specified position till the string ends in smarty?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, smarty, substr, smarty2

I want to implement the bootstrap's collapse functionality on a large text. But unfortunately it's not working as per the expectation. Following is the code I tried:

```
  {foreach from=$quant_vol_data item=data key=key}    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Details :</label>          
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        {$data.details|substr:0:100}
      </div>
      <div id="comment_{$data.id}" class="collapse out">
        {$data.details|substr:101:''} {* here I'm getting error since the end position is not mentioned *}
      </div>  
        {if $data.details|@count_characters > 101}
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comment_{$data.id}">Readmore...</a>
        {/if}
    </div>
  </div>
  {/foreach}
```

I want to get part of a string starting from position 101 till the end of string. But I'm not able to get it with above code. Can someone please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to omit the second number so you should use:

```
{$data.details|substr:101}
```